# Sort letters in string alphabetically- SAS

Tags: string, sorting, sas, alphabetical

I would like to sort the letters in a string alphabetically.

E.g.

```
'apple' = 'aelpp'
```

The only function I have seen that is somewhat similar is [SORTC](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003106052.htm), but I would like to avoid splitting each word into an array of letters if possible.

Comment: There's not a function that just does this, if that is what you're asking.  Have you made any attempt at this yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joe's right - there is no built-in function that does this. You have two options here that I can see:

1. Split your string into an array and sort the array using `call sortc`. You can do this fairly painlessly using `call pokelong` provided that you have first defined an array of sufficient length.
2. Implement a [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) of your choice. If you choose to go down this route, I would suggest using `substr` on the left of the `=` sign to change individual characters without rewriting the whole string.

Here's an example of how you might do #1. #2 would be much more work.

```
data _null_;
    myword = 'apple';
    array letters[5] $1;
    call pokelong(myword,addrlong(letters1),5); /*Limit # of chars to copy to the length of array*/
    call sortc(of letters[*]);
    myword = cat(of letters[*]);
    putlog _all_;
run;
```

N.B. for an array of length 5 as used here, make sure you only write the first 5 characters of the string into memory at the start of the array when using `call pokelong` in order to avoid overflowing past the end of the array - otherwise you could overwrite some other arbitrary section of memory when processing longer values of `myword`. This could cause undesirable side effects, e.g. application / system crashes. Also, this technique for populating the array will not work in SAS University Edition - if you're using that, you'll need to use a do-loop instead.

I did a little test of this - sorting 2m random words of length 100 consisting of characters chosen from the whole ASCII printable range took about 15 seconds using a single CPU of a several-years-old PC - slightly less time than it took to create the test dataset.

```
data have;
  length myword $100;
  do i = 1 to 2000000;
    do j = 1 to 100;
      substr(myword,j,1) = byte(32 + int(ranuni(1) * (126 - 32)));
    end;
    output;
  end;
  drop i j;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array letters[100] $1;
  call pokelong(myword,addrlong(letters1),100); /*Limit # of chars to copy to the length of array*/
  call sortc(of letters[*]);
  myword = cat(of letters[*]);  
  drop letters:;
run;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of how expensive #1 will be? I have approximately 2 million records. Ultimately, I will be using a second list and [SPEDIS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245949.htm) to search the closest match. I know this may be a strange way to do fuzzy matching, but there are outstanding circumstances that make me believe this is the best approach.

Comment: @JamesSteele Added a test - the limiting factor (as is usual for SAS) seems to be disk I/O.

Comment: This is a good solution, excepting one thing: spaces in blank strings.  I'd make two changes: one to the generating routine, one to the WANT datastep.

Comment: Here's a generator to shorten some: `data have;
  length myword $100;
  call streaminit(7);
  do i = 1 to 2000000;
    do j = 1 to 100;
      if rand('Uniform') < .05 and j > 5 then leave;
      substr(myword,j,1) = byte(32 + int(rand('Uniform') * (126 - 32)));
    end;
    output;
    call missing(myword);
  end;
  drop i j;
run;
`

Comment: And here's my suggested fix to WANT.  Also adding in temporary array b/c that is what you are intending to do, I think... (cannot get code formatting to work - note _ around temporary and asterisks in letters[ ] calls) ` data want;  set have; array letters[100] $1 _temporary_;  call pokelong(myword,addrlong(letters[1]),100);  call sortc(of letters[*]); myword = left(cat(of letters[*]));  run;  `

Comment: Finally - @JamesSteele, if you truly need fastest performance, C or Python is your best bet.  I think SAS is fine at this speed wise, but it's nothing close to C or Python.

Comment: @joe I tested this with a `_temporary_` array, but that resulted in the array being populated with garbage values. I suspect SAS uses a different memory layout for `_temporary_` arrays, preventing the `call pokelong` trick from working properly.

Comment: @user667489 Hmm, I tested it prior to posting that, and just verified again using a second `myword2`, and it worked correctly.  I am fairly sure temporary arrays are treated identically to regular arrays (in fact, they're slightly better in that they're _always_ contiguous; nontemporary arrays if the variables already existed may not be).  See http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/264-29.pdf for example.

Comment: @joe this may be version-specific behaviour - I'm using 9.1.3. I presume you've got something newer?

Comment: I do, but I can't Imagine this changes in between v9 versions... the linked paper was quite a while ago for example (2004) which would be squarely in the 9.1.3 timeframe.